# How to make browser fade after submitting a form

Tags: html

For some reason, my browser gets really ugly when I submit it (I mean divs and label stretch across the screen, buttons lose there images and also get stretched out.  It is very ugly.  How can I make the browser kind of blur or fade when submitting a form using jquery, HTML or any other technology.

Comment: Can you not just concentrate on fixing the issue instead of hiding it?

Comment: I will definitely fix it.  But the guys in test need to try and break it right now.
Thanks for the advice on how to fix it btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fade out the contents of the screen before submitting try

```
$("html, body").fadeOut(1000, function(){ $("#formId").submit(); });
```